# How to access a class from blenders python console?

Tags: python, command-line

I have an operator with a class name of say `Mesh_OT_Add_Thing`. Printing `self.__class__` shows that the class is `__main__.Mesh_OT_Add_Thing`. I've tried a few different ways but can't seem to get to the class to check a specific member.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to access your Operator class? I can successfully access another Operator class from the same directory using `from . import my_operator`. And I think it is also possible using class path.

Comment: From the python command line in blender. Ill try the import thing when i get time tomorrow and use the from [path] part you suggested and let you know the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access classes for registered operators via `bpy.types`.

eg:

```
cls = bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_make_dupli_face

import inspect

inspect.getsourcefile(cls)
# 'release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/object.py'

inspect.getsource(cls)
# 'class MakeDupliFace(Operator):\n    """Convert objects ... <snip>
```